# Insert dinámico de archivo con php mysqli y bind_param

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, crud

Estoy complementando una clase para operaciones `CRUD` hacia `mysql`. Estoy realizando un método para ejecutar sentencias `insert`, `update` y `delete`. Este es el código:

```
public function ejecutarSQL($sql,$parametrosSQL=array(),$tipos=null){
    if( $this->conexion){
        $parametros =array();
        if(count($parametrosSQL)>=1){
            foreach($parametrosSQL as $key => $value) {
                $parametros[] = utf8_decode($value);
            }
        }
        if (!($sentencia = $this->conexion->prepare($sql))) {
            $msg="Falló la preparación: (" . $this->conexion->errno . ") " . $this->conexion->error;
        }
        # bind parameters for markers
        # but this is not dynamic enough...
        //$stmt->bind_param("s", $parameter);

        //tipos:
        //i => entero
        //d => double,float
        //s => string
        //b => blob
        if($parametros&&$tipos){
            $bind_names[] = $tipos;
            $arraytipos=str_split($tipos); 
            for ($i=0; $i<count($parametros);$i++){
                if($arraytipos[$i]=='b'){
                    $bind_name = 'bind' . $i;
                    $null=NULL;
                    $$bind_name=$null;
                    $byteToSend = 1024;//this should equals the max_allowed_packet variable in your mysql config (usually in my.cnf config file)
                    $j=0;
                    while ($contentToSend = substr($parametros[$i], $j, $byteToSend)) {
                        $sentencia->send_long_data($i, $contentToSend);
                        $j+=$byteToSend;
                    }
                    $file=$parametros[$i];
                    $bind_names[] = &$file;
                }else{
                    $bind_name = 'bind' . $i;
                    $$bind_name = $this->conexion->real_escape_string($parametros[$i]);
                    $bind_names[] = &$$bind_name;
                }
            }
            $return = call_user_func_array(array($sentencia,'bind_param'),$bind_names);
        }
        if(!$sentencia->execute()){
            $msg= "Falló la ejecución: (" . $this->conexion->errno . ") " . $this->conexion->error;
        }else{                      
            $nowRows=$sentencia->affected_rows;
            if($nowRows>=1){
                $result = $this->conexion->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as ID;");
                while ($fila =  $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $datos_pr[] = $fila;
                }
                if ($datos_pr[0]["ID"] == null){
                    $datos =  "Registro exitoso";
                }else{
                    $datos=$datos_pr[0];
                }
                $datos_pr=null;
                $bandera=true;
            }else{
                $bandera=false;
                $msg = "Ocurrio un problema en la sentencia SQL y/o no se afectaron registros";
                $nowRows=0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

He probado este código con `inserts`, `updates` y `deletes` y funciona correctamente. El problema viene cuando intento guardar un archivo en un campo `blob`, ya que el `insert` se realiza correctamente, pero al revisar el campo `blob` en `mysql` esta vacío y no recibo ninguna tipo de error. La forma en que llamo a la función es esta:

```
$this->conexion=new Conexion("conexiones.properties");
$archivo=file_get_contents("C:/archivo.pdf");       
$query="INSERT INTO movie_prueba(title,year,raiting,image) VALUES (?,now(),?,?);";
$parametros=array('texto7',20, $archivo);
$res=$this->conexion->ejecutarSQL($query,$parametros,"sib" );
var_dump($res);
```

He debuggeado el código y todo parece estar bien, incluso el ciclo `while` `send_long_data` para el guardado del archivo se ejecuta bien, por lo que no entiendo que es lo que falla. Me he basado en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5108167/6009099) y en [esta otra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9864298/6009099).

Como veo que al debuggear el código se ejecuta aparentemente como debe, comienzo a pensar que el problema debe ser alguna configuración de `php`, de `mysql` o incluso del driver `mysqli`, pero lo desconozco. Espero me puedan apoyar.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Después de mucho debuggear encontré que en el objeto `$sentencia` si aparece un error. El error aparece al ejecutar `$sentencia->send_long_data($i, $contentToSend);` La variable con el error tiene esto:

`[[0] => [[errno] => 2014, [sqlstate] => HY000, [error] => Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now]]`

aunque ya lo busque sigo sin entender porque aparece, ya que he encontrado que aparece al tratar de ejecutar dos instrucciones al mismo tiempo, pero yo solo ejecuto una.

Comment: `mysqli` tiene sus lagunas en el manejo de datos blob, sobre todo si el archivo es muy grande, quizá necesites [recurrir a esto](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data.php), lee las explicaciones y los ejemplos. Si yo estuviera en tu lugar PDO para esto. El paso de parámetros dinámicos es mucho más simple que todo el spaghetti que hay que hacer en estos casos si se usa `mysqli` y por algo muy simple: PDO permite para un array de parámetros en el `execute` de las consultas preparadas y esto simplifica la vida, más aún en casos como este.

Comment: No puedo usar PDO porque como mencione estoy complementando una clase que ya estaba hecha, por lo mismo no puedo quitar lo que ya estaba hecho. Por otra parte, si revisaste el código si estoy usando `send_long_data`, pero aún así no me funciona.

Comment: ¿Si pruebas una consulta preparada para insertar el blob, fuera de la clase y esos métodos no funciona? ¿Definiste el tipo de dato correcto para la columna que almacena el blob? ¿Revisaste el log de errores por si hay alguna advertencia? Otra cosa que necesitas verificar es el valor actual de `max_allowed_packet` con esta consulta: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';` para saber cómo debes dividir el blob.

Comment: [Revisa también esto](https://blogs.oracle.com/oswald/phps-mysqli-extension:-storing-and-retrieving-blobs). Tanto ahí como en el Manual el código usa `fopen` , no sé si eso influya, pero trata de usar el código como ellos lo indican, primero sólo y si funciona entonces lo incorporas a la clase.

Comment: a mi me suena mas a que no cierras la sentencia. Se ejecuta pero esta en el buffer el insert cuando se esta ejecutando el select de last_insert_id. Te sugiero que antes de esta ultima sentencia la cierres con `$sentencia->close();`

Comment: @Jakala hace unos días estaba haciendo unas pruebas con `mysqli` y constaté que en ciertos casos era mejor usar `$sentencia=null` que `$sentencia->close()`. No recuerdo el escenario ahora, pero cuando hacía `var_dump($sentencia);` al usar `close()` seguían apareciendo cosas. No le di seguimiento a eso por falta de tiempo...

Comment: @Jakala Tenia razón (a medias) en que no se cerraba la conexión, existe una función `cerrarConexión` a la que yo estaba llamando, pero en el código interno no hacia `conexión->close()`, cuando lo puse fallo porque la conexión ya estaba cerrada, al buscar porque encontré en el destructor la llamada a `cerrarConexión`, así que quite mi propia llamada y solo deje la del destructor. Ya no tengo errores al cerrar la conexión pero el error motivo de la pregunta persiste.

Comment: He visto que a varios les funcionan esta 3 lineas `mysql_free_result($resultado);
mysql_close($conexionEscritura);
unset($resultado,$conexionEscritura);` pero considero que es una mala manera de darle la vuelta, porque ademas de que eso te impide hacer transacciones, también impide recuperar el id creado por un nuevo registro con un `insert` usando `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. Todo eso es debido a que cierras la conexión. Intente usarlo pero no me funciona porque necesito el `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Comment: El problema que planteas es la inserción cuando hay datos blob, ¿cierto? ¿Que hay de lo que te sugerí de hacer una prueba fuera de la clase, o sea, una prueba directa con la misma consulta y los mismos datos con que falla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema viene porque estás usando la funcions de `send_long_data` antes de llamar `bind_param`.

Trata cambiando el orden y llamando primero el `bind_param`. También, revisa si `send_long_data` deveuelve satisfactoriamente antes de ejeutar la sentencia.

Comment: Si es eso ya me quedo ayer, apenas iba a publicarlo.

Comment: Te voy a dar los puntos para que no se pierdan, pero tu respuesta llego cuando ya lo había resuelto.

Answer (score 1):

Esta es la solución:

```
public function ejecutarSQL($sql,$parametrosSQL=array(),$tipos=null){
    if( $this->conexion){
        if (!($sentencia = $this->conexion->prepare($sql))) {
            $msg="Falló la preparación: (" . $this->conexion->errno . ") " . $this->conexion->error;
        }
        //$sentencia->free();
        # bind parameters for markers
        # but this is not dynamic enough...
        //$stmt->bind_param("s", $parameter);

        //tipos:
        //i => entero
        //d => double,float
        //s => string
        //b => blob
        if($parametrosSQL&&$tiposMysql){
            $bind_names[] = $tiposMysql;
            $arraytipos=str_split($tiposMysql);
            $posicionesBlob=array();
            for ($i=0; $i<count($parametrosSQL);$i++){
                $bind_name = 'bind' . $i;
                if($arraytipos[$i]=='b'){
                    array_push($posicionesBlob,$i);//guardo la posicion de los blob en los $parametros
                    $$bind_name=null;
                }else{
                    $$bind_name = $this->conexion->real_escape_string($parametrosSQL[$i]);
                }
                $bind_names[] = &$$bind_name;
            }
            $return = call_user_func_array(array($sentencia,'bind_param'),$bind_names);//ejecuto los bind_param con los parametros
            if(!empty($posicionesBlob)){//ciclo para guardar archivos blob
                foreach ($posicionesBlob as $clave => $valor){
                    $byteToSend = 2048;//this should equals the max_allowed_packet variable in your mysql config (usually in my.cnf config file)
                    $j=0;
                    while($contentToSend = substr($parametrosSQL[$valor], $j, $byteToSend)) {
                        $sentencia->send_long_data($valor, $contentToSend);//$valor es la posicion qu quiero guardar
                        $j+=$byteToSend;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (!$sentencia->execute()) {
            $msg= "Falló la ejecución: (" . $this->conexion->errno . ") " . $this->conexion->error;
        }else{                      
            error_log(print_r($sentencia,true));
            $nowRows=$sentencia->affected_rows;
            if($nowRows>=1){
                $result = $this->conexion->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as ID;");
                while ($fila =  $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $datos_pr[] = $fila;
                }
                if ($datos_pr[0]["ID"] == null){
                    $datos =  "Registro exitoso";
                }else{
                    $datos=$datos_pr[0];
                }
                $datos_pr=null;
                $bandera=true;
            }else{
                $bandera=false;
                $msg = "Ocurrio un problema en la sentencia SQL y/o no se afectaron registros";
                $nowRows=0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cabe mencionar que la solución de usar `fopen` funciona, pero no para lo que pretende esta función ya que los archivos pueden venir de disco, de WebServices o de base de datos y usando `fopen` solo vendrían de disco. Y ojo con esta asignación `$byteToSend = 2048;` queda a su criterio, aunque en uno de los links en que me base recomiendan que sea igual que `max_allowed_packet`